# Is it possible to trigger a Hotstring with a double space? If not by Hotstring can it be done another way?

Tags: autohotkey

My goal is to have certain acronyms expanded like a Hotstring when followed by a quick double space but left as an acronym when followed by a single space.

From what I have been reading it might not be possible to define this as a hotstring. I assume checking every space input for a double press would not be very efficient and would like to avoid that if this is the case.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is certainly possible, though it *may mean* changing all of your existing hotstrings that currently behave as you expect, especially you usually triggered these with space. As you may know, space is an [ending character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars), so for a double-space to be detected, we will have to remove it from the `EndChars`. Something like:

```
#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/\,.?!`n`t
;;; (Notice there is no space between `n and `t.)
```

With this, you'll now need to add two spaces after your acronyms or initialisms to have them be replaced with the phrase.

```
:*:btw  ::buy the whey
:*:wtf  ::well thought-out, friend{!}
:*:lol  ::I didn't really laugh audibly, but I thought it was mildly amusing
```

Comment: In this arrangement I would not be able to use a single space for any regular hotkey. 
If the modification to the end characters occurs at the end of the file would I then be able treat only the hotstrings below it by those conditions or would the above also be affected?